# How to calculate the euclidean distance between a vector and a 3-D tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor **A** with the size of (1，*L*),  and a 3-D tensor **B** with the size of (*N*, *K*, *L*). Obviously, there are *N* arrays with the size of (*K*, *L*) in **B**, which are called **C** here.

Now, how can I calculate the **mean euclidean distance** (average the distance of **A** and each row of **C**) between **A** and every **C** without iterations of every rows in **C**, and finally return a vector with the size of (1,*N*) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [`tf.norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/norm) and [`tf.reduce_mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_mean):

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None])
    b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None])
    dist = tf.reduce_mean(tf.norm(b - a, axis=2), axis=1)
    print(sess.run(dist, feed_dict={a: [[1, 2, 3]],
                                    b: [[[ 4,  5,  6], [ 7,  8,  9]],
                                        [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]]}))
    # [ 7.7942286 18.186533 ]
```

EDIT: A variation for the case where you have several vectors in `a`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None])
    b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None])
    a_exp = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(a, 1), 1)
    dist = tf.reduce_mean(tf.norm(b - a_exp, axis=3), axis=2)
    print(sess.run(dist, feed_dict={a: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
                                    b: [[[ 4,  5,  6], [ 7,  8,  9]],
                                        [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]]}))
    # [[ 7.7942286 18.186533 ]
    #  [ 2.598076  12.990381 ]]
```

Comment: Furthermore, if the tensor A with the shape of [?,L] (where "?" is the batch size), how can I obtain the results with the shape of [?,N]? I have tried the solution above, but it didn't work.

Comment: @BoboXi I have edited the answer slightly (adding a `tf.expand_dims`) so it works for that case as well.

Comment: I have tried it, but it didn't work well. Assuming that  a = ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) with a shape of (2, 3) when the batch_size = 2, while b remains the value above. It is supposed that I should get the result with the shape of (2, 2), of which the first row is the distance between [1, 2, 3] and the 3-D tensor denoted a,  and the second row is the distance between [4, 5, 6] and a. But the code above returns the result  [ 7.7942286 12.990381 ] with the shape of (1, 2), it is obviously not correct.

Comment: @BoboXi Ah I think I understand what you mean now. See if the edited answer helps.